# AWS CloudWatch logstream data completely missing

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am looking for help in troubleshooting a curious CloudWatch issue.

I have a CloudWatch logshipping agent setup for `/var/log/syslog` on Ubuntu.

The aws log is full of happy INFO messages such as the following. No errors, no exceptions:
[image: Screenshot]

The log stream in CloudWatch console is completely empty - no data whatsoever. I tried manually creating the logstream using the instance name (matching the name from the log) - no improvement.

The instance is using IAM role with the following policy, which works perfectly fine for other instances:

```
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
            "ec2:DescribeTags",
            "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
            "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

Comment: Can you check if you have the right permission for writing to cloudwatch log stream

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar I think I do. I updated the question with relevant detail

Comment: I had this problem, but it turned out that python's `time.time()` epoch timestamp was in seconds, not milliseconds like AWS - so I had to add time*1000 and then events appeared.